# XSLT and PHP: $_REQUEST in hidden field

Tags: php, xslt, hidden-field

I am posting hidden values in `hidden` fields to another form like this:

```
<xsl:element name="input">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="'server'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="'hidden'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@server"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

But this is only working when I can put the value of an attribute or element like above.

How would I pass the value of a request through such as `$_REQUEST['nq']`?

`$_REQUEST['nq']` is coming from the PHP page that is being styled by this XSLT page.

I tried this:

```
<xsl:element name="input">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="'hidden'"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="'value'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="$nq"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

But it doesn't work!

The XSLT is run by putting this at the end of the PHP page:

```
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc>load('nginxSearchFull.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt>importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $xslt>transformtoXML($xmlDom1);
```

Comment: What is `$_REQUEST['nq']`, is that PHP? How are you running the XSLT?

Comment: Please add more details to the question like what exactly you are trying to do and what you have right now

Comment: Why all this verbose code, when you could write `<input type="hidden" name="value" value="{$nq}"/>`. Do they pay you by the number of lines of code you write?

Comment: I'm just learning XSLT at the moment. I've tried that way before, but was just changing it to see what happened. Cheers though, at least I know it'll work that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a global `<xsl:param name="nq"/>` in your XSLT code, then you can use `<input type="hidden" name="value" value="{$nq}"/>` as suggested by Michael Kay, if you set `$xslt->setParameter('', 'nq', $_REQUEST['nq']);` in your PHP, before calling the transform method on the XSLTProcessor.